# Sort xsl strips xsi:schemaLocation for custom domain

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to sort an xml file but when I run the transform, it strips he xsi:schemaLocation from the header. Strangely, if I change the namespace url to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it will not be removed.  I'm really perplexed with this.

so an `xsltproc sort.xsl test.xml` will return this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lexique xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <headword>
    <dyu>à</dyu>
```

But if I change the url to example.com the same transform will return:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lexique xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com headwords.xsd">
  <headword>
    <dyu>bôn</dyu>
```

test.xml:

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>                                                                                                           
<lexique xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net"    
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.coastsystems.net headwords.xsd"    
  >    
  <headword>    
    <dyu>bôn</dyu>       
    <alt></alt>    
    <trans>       
      <lang>fr</lang>    
      <detail></detail>    
      <speech>    
        <type></type>      
        <def>    
          <gloss>lancer</gloss>    
          <note></note>    
          <example>     
            <source></source>    
            <target></target>    
          </example>    
        </def>    
      </speech>    
    </trans>        
  </headword>  
 <headword>
    <dyu>à</dyu>
    <alt></alt>
    <trans>
      <lang>fr</lang>
      <detail></detail>
      <speech>
        <type>pr 3è s.</type>
        <def>
          <gloss>il / elle</gloss>
          <note></note>
          <example>
            <source>Musa k'a dɔgɔcɛ bugɔ.</source>
            <target>Moussa a frappé son frère.</target>
          </example>
        </def>
      </speech>
    </trans>
  </headword>
</lexique>
```

sort.xsl

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>                                                                                                                           
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
xmlns:z="http://www.coastsystems.net"    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
>    
    
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>        
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>        
    
<xsl:template match="z:lexique">        
  <xsl:copy>    
    <xsl:apply-templates>    
      <xsl:sort select="z:dyu" lang="en" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>    
    </xsl:apply-templates>    
  </xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template>        
    
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">    
  <xsl:copy>    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>    
  </xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template>        
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

headwords.xsd:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                           
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.coastsystems.net" xmlns:xs="http://www.w
  <xs:element name="lexique" type="coas:lexiqueType" xmlns:coas="http://www.coastsystems.net"/>    
    
  <xs:complexType name="exampleType">    
    <xs:sequence>    
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="source"/>    
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="target"/>    
    </xs:sequence>    
  </xs:complexType>    
    
  <xs:complexType name="defType">    
    <xs:sequence>    
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="gloss"/>    
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="note">    
      </xs:element>    
      <xs:element type="coas:exampleType" name="example" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" xmlns:coas="http://www.coastsystems.net"/>    
    </xs:sequence>    
  </xs:complexType>    
    
  <xs:complexType name="speechType">    
    <xs:sequence>    
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="type"/>    
      <xs:element type="coas:defType" name="def" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" xmlns:coas="http://www.coastsystems.net"/>    
    </xs:sequence>    
  </xs:complexType>    
  <xs:complexType name="transType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="lang"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="detail">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element type="coas:speechType" name="speech" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" xmlns:coas="http://www.coastsystems.net"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="headwordType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="dyu"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="alt" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element type="coas:transType" name="trans" xmlns:coas="http://www.coastsystems.net"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="lexiqueType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="coas:headwordType" name="headword" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" xmlns:coas="http://www.coastsystems.net"/>
    </xs:sequence>                                                                                                                               
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It's not the `xsi:schemaLocation`, you must be doing something else wrong. Show a sample XML file that exhibits the behavior.

Comment: If you post a sample of input and the expected corresponding output, we could try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please explain the symptoms. What do you mean by "it breaks"? Without knowing the symptoms, diagnosis is difficult...

Comment: Sorry about changing the subject.  I realized when gathering some sample data that I should't require extra code to reinsert the schemaLocation.   Something else is causing the sort transform to remove it.  Although  note that when its my domain (coastsystems.net, the data is sorted.  but when I change it to example.com, the schemallocation is inserted that the data is no longer sorted.  Note the first words returned starting with a or b.

Comment: Do you adjust the XSLT if the XML has a different namespace?

Comment: Yes I had generated the above xsd which made a namespace of coas.  I changed the xslt to reflect that (replacing z: with coas:.   But still the same result.   With the url that corresponds to what is in the xsd (coast systems)  the sort.xsl strips out the xsi:schemaLocation.

Comment: *"but when I change it to example.com, [...] the data is no longer sorted"* - ...where do you change it to "example.com"? In the XSLT namespace declaration, from `xmlns:z="http://www.coastsystems.net"` to `xmlns:z="http://example.com"`? Because that is the only location where it behaves the way you say. When you change that, the output is no longer sorted, because `<xsl:template match="z:lexique">` does no longer apply to your document.

Comment: Apart from that, note that XSLT 1.0 is unable to sort French correctly, because that would require Unicode collation knowledge, which has been introduced into the language with XSLT 2.0.

Comment: ok thank you I get it for changing the domain name.   What was I thinking?   But then why when the namespace is ok, the xsi:schema is removed from the output.   And yes I did see some issues with sorting.   But lang=en seems to be somewhat better than nothing.   (Saw a post about that elsewhere.)    And I'm actually sorting in Jula, which has extended latin characters.  But haven't seen any opensource tools that process xslt 2 or 3 on command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xsl:copy>` only copies the element, not the attributes.
So you have to copy the attributes of the root-node as well. For i.e. like this: `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>`

This xslt:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
  xmlns:z="http://www.coastsystems.net"    
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
  >    
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>        
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>        
  
  <xsl:template match="z:lexique">        
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>    
      <xsl:apply-templates>    
        <xsl:sort select="z:dyu" lang="en" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>    
      </xsl:apply-templates>    
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>        
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">    
    <xsl:copy>    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>    
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>        
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lexique xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.coastsystems.net headwords.xsd">
   <headword>
      <dyu>à</dyu>
      <alt/>
      <trans>
         <lang>fr</lang>
         <detail/>
         <speech>
            <type>pr 3è s.</type>
            <def>
               <gloss>il / elle</gloss>
               <note/>
               <example>
                  <source>Musa k'a dɔgɔcɛ bugɔ.</source>
                  <target>Moussa a frappé son frère.</target>
               </example>
            </def>
         </speech>
      </trans>
   </headword>
   <headword>
      <dyu>bôn</dyu>
      <alt/>
      <trans>
         <lang>fr</lang>
         <detail/>
         <speech>
            <type/>
            <def>
               <gloss>lancer</gloss>
               <note/>
               <example>
                  <source/>
                  <target/>
               </example>
            </def>
         </speech>
      </trans>
   </headword>
</lexique>
```